# Pushing into subdocument with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this data structure. I would like to push a new sibling into a specific members sibling array:

```
const FamilySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: { type: String, required: true }, 
    family_name: { type: String, required: true }, 
    password: { type: String, required: true }, 
    members: [
        {
            fname: { type: String, required: true }, 
            lname: { type: String, required: true }, 
            mname: { type: String }, 
            birth_date: { type: String },
            birth_town: { type: String }, 
            birth_state: { type: String },  
            death_date: { type: String }, 
            death_town: { type: String }, 
            death_state: { type: String }, 
            short_bio: { type: String }, 
            long_bio: {type: String }, 
            parents: [
                { 
                    parent_id: { type: String, required: true }
                } 
            ], 
            siblings: [
                { 
                    sibling_id: { type: String, required: true }
                } 
            ],
            children: [
                { 
                    children_id: { type: String, required: true }
                } 
            ], 
            pictures: [
                { 
                    url: { type: String, required: true }
                } 
            ],  

        }
    ]
});
```

I want to push a new sibling into the sibling array for a SPECIFIC member in the larger family document. I'm trying to do it like this, and it's not working.

```
                    Family
                        .update(
                        { 
                            _id: FAMILY_ID,
                            "members._id" : MEMBER_ID 
                        },
                        {
                            $push : {
                                "members.$.siblings" : {
                                    "sibling_id": THE_VALUE_I_WANT_ADDED
                                }
                            } 
                        }
                    );
```

Any thoughts? My Mongoose knowledge is failing me.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Oddly, there is no error. It just doesn't do it.